# Print Layout button disabled in MS Word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an MS Word document that seems to be formatted in such a way that it cannot be printed.

The document opens in Draft view. I am able to access all the other views (Full Screen Reading, Web Layout, Outline), but the Print Layout button is disabled.

In addition, when I click on Print, the document does not print.

How can I reformat the document so that it is printable?

Comment: can you print other documents?

Comment: Yes, I can print all other documents

Comment: is there a part of the document you can print? You haven't got something like a table that spans multiple pages in part of the document?

Comment: The document does indeed have a table that spans several pages. I am able to print the table if I copy-and-paste it into a new document, so the problem seems to be with the document formatting and not with the table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the document in question doesn't have some kind of crazy VBA in it to prevent printing, it sounds like something is just corrupted with that document.

Suggestion:

- Create a new Word Document.
- Copy content from troublesome document.
- Paste it into the new document.
- Save new document.
- Print new document.